# spark scala create key value pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have schema like :

```
       root
      |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      |-- info: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
      |    |    |-- _2: long (nullable = false)
      |    |    |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
```

Info is an array of structs. I want to make `info_1` as key and `info_2` and `info_3` as values after grouping by `id`. So the o/p should be like :

```
id,[[info[0]_1:{info[0]_2,info[0]_3}],[info[1]_1:{{info[1]_2,info[1]_3},...]
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried any code for this? Kindly share that along with the error you are getting.

Comment: Nope i havent tried .

Comment: can you share some sample input?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started (UDF-approach):

```
val df = Seq(
      ("1", Seq(("a", 1L, "b"), ("c", 2L, "d"))
  )
).toDF("id", "info")


df.show()

+---+------------------+
| id|              info|
+---+------------------+
|  1|[[a,1,b], [c,2,d]]|
+---+------------------+


val transformStructToMap = udf((structarray : Seq[Row]) => {
    structarray.map(r =>
        (r.getString(0), // key
        (r.getLong(1),r.getString(2))) // values
     ).toMap
 })

df.select(
   $"id",
   transformStructToMap($"info").as("info")
 ).show()

+---+---------------------------+
|id |info                       |
+---+---------------------------+
|1  |Map(a -> [1,b], c -> [2,d])|
+---+---------------------------+
```

I don't really understand what you mean by "after grouping". If you want to concatenate the arrays after grouping by id, you would need to `collect_list` and then use an udf to concatenate (and flatten) the arrays first